# How to form a C++ string from concatenations of string literals?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, literals, string-concatenation

I would like concatenate string literals and ints, like  this:
`string message("That value should be between " + MIN_VALUE + " and " + MAX_VALUE);`

But that gives me this error:

`error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [6]’ to binary ‘operator+’|`

What is the correct way to do that? I could split that in 2 string declarations (each concatenating a string literal and a int), but that's ugly. I've also tried << operator.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably use stringstream for this.

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream s;
s << "This value shoud be between " << MIN_VALUE << " and " << MAX_VALUE;
message = s.str();
```

Comment: It would be nice if there was a simpler way. But thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string Str( const T & t ) {
     std::ostringstream os;
     os << t;
     return os.str();
}



std::string message = "That value should be between " + Str( MIN_VALUE ) 
                       + " and " + Str( MAX_VALUE );
```

Comment: Or use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm), which is pretty much your `Str` template.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a stringstream like this:

```
std::stringstream msgstream;
msgstream << "That value should be between " << MIN_VALUE << " and " <<  MAX_VALUE;
std::string message(msgstream.c_str());
```

Comment: Where are the upvotes coming from? This syntax is all sorts of broken.

Answer (score 1):

The c++ way to do this is to use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) then you can use the << operator.  It will give you a more consistent code feel

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but my favourite is:

```
string message(string("That value should be between ") + MIN_VALUE + " and " + MAX_VALUE);
```

That extra `string()` around the first literal makes all the difference in the world because there is an overloaded `string::operator+(const char*)` which returns a `string`, and `operator+` has left-to-right associativity, so the whole thing is turned into a chain of `operator+` calls.

Comment: `std::string` overloads + for char types, but not for integers, so if `MIN_VALUE` is not a string of some sort, this may well compile into something unexpected.

Comment: Right, but in this case `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` are string literals.

Comment: The compiler error he pasted suggests that, but he talks about concatenating ints, so I figure its an important consideration.  I do the same in my code, for what its worth, which is why I know the int->char conversion can bite you if you're not watching out for it :-)

Comment: Indeed. I've actually written for myself a templated operator+(string, T) which takes any type and stringstream-converts it to a string... not sure if there's any gotchas with that, but I haven't run into any so far.

Comment: I see. In that case, use stringstreams as people have mentioned. If you find them cumbersome, you can use `boost::lexical_cast` (or write your own). In C++0x there will be an `std::to_string()` function which handles built-in numeric types.